# Windows 10 - Dynamic folder icons in windows explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

I know you can manually customize the icon of a folder, but I'm wondering if there is a way to have the icon change themselves.

For example, if there is an empty folder on the desktop background, the icon is an empty folder.. When I put a document in the folder, the icon is updated to a new icon with a file in it. Ideally I'd like to have that same functionality in explorer itself, but it only displays empty folders for everything. This would be very helpful in the large directories that I am dealing with, or to be able to (at the very least) have a visual indication whether the folder is empty or not so I'm not wasting my time opening empty folders.

Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

What view mode are you using? **Details** & **List** use static folder icons, but **Icon**, **Tiles**, & **Content** all display dynamic fodler icons.

Comment: It'd be nice if Details & List would be dynamic. It seems the other options that you listed ARE dynamic, but as I drill down into a directory, it gets to a point where that "stops working" too, and only displays an empty icon.